# Searching for values in large dataframe with unnamed columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with ~300 columns in the following format:

```
| Column1     | Column2        | Column3   | Column5
| ------------| -------------- |-----------|----------
| Color=Blue  | Location=USA   | Name=Steve| N/A
| Location=USA| ID=123         | Name=Randy| Color=Purple
| ID=987      | Name=Gary      | Color=Red | Location=Italy
```

What is the best way to process such a huge and irregular dataset if I'm only interested in specific attributes, such as 'Color' and 'ID'?

An example output if I only wanted to see 'ID' could be something like:

```
| Column1     | Column2        | Column3   | Column5
| ------------| -------------- |-----------|----------
| ID=987=     | ID=123         |           |
```

Or maybe even a list of results would work:

```
ID=[987, 123]
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and put there example output for specific input?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Updated. My main issue is not really knowing how to slice such a dataframe; there could be many outputs that work well.

Comment: Have you considered parsing the attributes into separate columns? That would make the most sense to me. To take that a step further, how are you loading this data? Is it possible to have the attributes end up in columns in the first place? The order of attributes in a row is not significant, right?

Comment: This is the output I'm being given in a CSV. Parsing the attributes is a good idea, however I have about ~200 unique attributes. I'm quite confused as to the most efficient way to begin processing this. Order is not significant.

Comment: @NRH *"Parsing the attributes is a good idea, however I have about ~200 unique attributes."* - Sorry, what's the problem? They're all in the same format, no? The name (a word) followed by an equals followed by the value.

Comment: @NRH As a rule of thumb, don't worry about **the best** way to do something until you have **a** way to do something.

Comment: @wjandrea I agree. My problem is I hate redoing things because I see it as a waste of time. However, that is something I need to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future process, maybe you can reorganize your dataframe?

```
piv = (pd.concat([df[c].str.split('=', expand=True) for c in df.columns])
         .set_index(0, append=True)[1].dropna()
         .unstack().rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Output:

```
>>> piv
    Color   ID Location   Name
0    Blue  NaN      USA  Steve
1  Purple  123      USA  Randy
2     Red  987    Italy   Gary
```

Usage:

```
>>> piv['ID'].dropna()
1    123
2    987
Name: ID, dtype: object

>>> piv['ID'].dropna().tolist()
['123', '987']
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the output I'm given; reorganizing is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
a = df.where(df.map(lambda x: str(x).startswith("ID"))).values.flatten()
a[~pd.isnull(a)].tolist()
```

Alternatively:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^ID")

a = df.where(df.map(lambda x: bool(pattern.match(str(x))))).values.flatten()
a[~pd.isnull(a)].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['ID=123', 'ID=987']
```

Comment: How efficient would regex be if there were ~200 unique delimited values to look for in each row? I'm wondering if it's better to try and re-structure the entire dataframe instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, without experimenting, I cannot say how efficient it is, @NRH.

Answer (score 1):

With quick [`numpy.char.find`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.find.html) method to find a pattern by a valid index (not `-1`):

```
df.values[np.char.find(df.values.astype(str), 'ID=') != -1].tolist()
```

---

```
['ID=123', 'ID=987']
```